# Stream webm using vlc

Tags: stream, vlc

I'm trying to use a linux terminal to receive a rtsp stream and transmit it to webm

```
cvlc -I dummy rtsp://192.168.2.169:554/live/ch03_0 --sout "#transcode{vcodec=VP80,vb=500,scale=Auto,width=200,height=100,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=webm,dst=:8081/stream} "
```

This stream was created using vlc's GUI (Generated stream output string)

Vlc returns:

```
[0x8c5c814] inhibit interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: /usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.

[0x8c5c814] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x8c578ec] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x8bbd0d4] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0x8c578ec] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[0x8c4eb9c] main access out: creating httpd
[0x8c4d684] stream_out_standard stream out error: no suitable sout mux module for `http/webm://:8081/stream'
[0x8c4d244] main stream output error: stream chain failed for `transcode{vcodec=VP80,vb=500,scale=Auto,width=200,height=100,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=webm,dst=:8081/stream} '
[0x8c639e4] main input error: cannot start stream output instance, aborting
```

Then I went [here](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch03.html) to check how to transmit webm but "webm" is nowhere to be found.